JKP data and French library data
I am currently using the JKP factor dataset (https://jkpfactors.com/) to test a large number of factors.
Their data has information on 153 factors, but no CAPM beta.
This dataset only supports returns.
I want to get the CAPM alpha of these factors, so I want to use the market beta data provided by the French library(https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html#Research).
According to the JKP documentation, their weighting method seems to be different from the French one.
I have a question for anyone who has worked with these two pieces of data.
Can I use the French library data to get the alpha for the JKP factor data?

This question is too similar to: What data sources are available online?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
